# How large are various gems?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance

I have a homebrew hilt of a weapon that changes what form it is depending on what kind of gem is placed inside of it. I am trying to figure out what size the gems should be in order to be used with the hilt without breaking the economy by giving them fist-sized gems for it that they sell and make 1000s of gold. The worst gems (malachite amber lapis etc) might do an extra 1d4 elemental damage while diamonds would likely do 2d10 extra force damage or something similar.

Comment: Hey there Ayebrow, I have closed this as a duplicate since a question about the size of gemstones has been asked and answered before. If there is some other aspect of magic item balance you want to ask about, edit the question to focus on that (see our guidance on asking homebrew review for some help: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121)).